# Интеграция интернет-магазина с 1с

Tags: 1с, интернет-магазин

Добрый день, друзья! Делаю магазин на ModX, реализовал весь функционал, кроме интеграции сайта с 1с. Читал немного про commerceML. Предавался размышлениям над тем, каким макаром все это прикрутить к своему магазину, задавался риторическими вопросами). Кто может дать дельный совет, как все это реализовать малой кровью, без больших затрат во времени?) Может, есть уже готовые библиотеки для этих целей или хотя бы внятная инструкция для тех, кто впервые интегрирует 1с и свой интернет-магазин, по возможности в связке с Modx, ну или хотя бы просто общий материал для любого интернет-магазина? Буду благодарен за ответы!

Comment: А конкретно в чем трудности?

Comment: @Ale_x, трудностей много. Во-первых, у меня стоит 1с Управление торговлей, редакция 11.1 (11.1.7.49), пытался настроить 1с для взаимодествия сайта по инструкции: http://www.divier.ru/stati/vygruzka_v_bitriks_instruktsii/vygruzka_v_bitriks_iz_1s_upravlenie_torgovley_11_1_2_9.html и ничего похожего там не нашел даже. Синхронизация данных не предусматривает обмена данных с сайтом. Вторая проблема, что все что я видел, реализовано для 1с-Битрикс, для CMS ModX даже ничего такого нет... Потому и буксую, прошу помощи у тех кто с этим работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот открыл 1C УТ 11.1 демо-базу) зашел с правами администратора. У меня НА вкладке Администрование слева появляется меню, и там 3 строчка Настройка Синхронизации данных.
Открываешь ее и добавляешь новый обмен с сайтом. Для начала Сделай выгрузку в файл, посмотри его структуру и пиши парсинг)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, нашел эту настройку, но насчет обмена данных с сайтом в моем случае, мне кажется, по-другому надо. Может быть, слышали про компонент mSklad, на нем, скорее всего, буду реализовать.